# Меняется кодировка json файла после удаления элемента списка из словаря

Tags: python, json, кодировка

Есть файл `test.json` с содержимым:

```
{
    "фрукты": [
        "абрикос",
        "апельсин",
        "яблоко"
    ],
    "овощи": [
        "картошка",
        "помидор",
        "морковь"
    ],
    "ягоды": [
        "черника",
        "слива",
        "черешня"
    ]
}
```

Этот файл представляет собой **словарь со вложенным списком**, откуда я удаляю только **один элемент списка**. Для этого был написан код:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json


delete_text = input()


with open('test.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    base = json.load(f)

base['фрукты'].remove(delete_text)

with open('test.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(base, f)
```

Для примера, я обращусь по ключу `фрукты` и удалю в нем элемент списка `яблоко`. Ввод в `input()`:

```
> яблоко
```

Выбранный элемент удаляется, но содержимое файла `test.json` **меняет кодировку**:

```
{"\u0444\u0440\u0443\u043a\u0442\u044b": ["\u0430\u0431\u0440\u0438\u043a\u043e\u0441", "\u0430\u043f\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0441\u0438\u043d"], "\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0449\u0438": ["\u043a\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043e\u0448\u043a\u0430", "\u043f\u043e\u043c\u0438\u0434\u043e\u0440", "\u043c\u043e\u0440\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044c"], "\u044f\u0433\u043e\u0434\u044b": ["\u0447\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0430", "\u0441\u043b\u0438\u0432\u0430", "\u0447\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0448\u043d\u044f"]}
```

Как мне сохранить кодировку, чтобы кириллица не превращалась в юникод? Т.е. после удаления элемента должно быть так:

```
{
    "фрукты": [
        "абрикос",
        "апельсин"
    ],
    "овощи": [
        "картошка",
        "помидор",
        "морковь"
    ],
    "ягоды": [
        "черника",
        "слива",
        "черешня"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В момент, когда вы производите `dump` вашего нового `json`, установите параметры `ensure_ascii=False` и `indent=4`, на вашем примере это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
import json

delete_text = input()

with open('test.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    base = json.load(f)

base['фрукты'].remove(delete_text)

with open('test.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(base, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4) #вот здесь мы выставили параметры
```

После исполнения кода, результат `test.json`:

```
{
    "фрукты": [
        "абрикос",
        "апельсин"
    ],
    "овощи": [
        "картошка",
        "помидор",
        "морковь"
    ],
    "ягоды": [
        "черника",
        "слива",
        "черешня"
    ]
}
```